# On server it is application/javascript extension js and mine is application/x-javascript

Tags: javascript, mime-types

I have one javascript file whose mime type is application/x-javascript and on my server, In MIME details , js is for application/javascript

My javascript is not showing proper output.

what can be solution ?

Comment: What have you tested yourself? Did you debug the script t see what is wrong. Does the script execute at all?

Comment: @Luc When I tried same script on my other server, It is working....

Comment: Does the script run at all? Check fiddler to see if there are missing resources...